# DBCollection.count doesn't count all its DBObjects

Tags: java, mongodb

I have some pretty big DBObjects of which I want to store basic information in an array. I count them, initialize the array in the correct size and then fill it with their basic information. Right now, the count method gives back 5, but there are 6 objects and the iteration finds them all.

```
public DBObject[] allDbObjects() {
    long count = dbc.coll.count();
    System.out.println(count + " results found");
    DBObject[] results = new DBObject[(int) count];
    int i=0;
    DBCursor cursor = dbc.coll.find();
    for (DBObject o: cursor) {
        System.out.println("Found one project:");
        results[i] = new BasicDBObject();
        System.out.println(o.get("name"));
        results[i].put("name", o.get("name"));
        results[i].put("id", o.get("_id"));
        results[i].put("description", o.get("description"));
        i++;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Obviously, this gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for the last object. It tries to access results[5], which doesn't exist.

This has worked fine before and according to the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/), the find method works with the cursor. So basically the cursor thinks it has 5 objects first and then it gives me 6.

Where did I go wrong?

UPDATE: I changed this one to an ArrayList and it works, but I do the same thing at another place. That one worked just fine yesterday. Today it doesn't, I get the same error as I did in the code above.

Comment: Strange behavior... but you can switch to a `List<DBObject>`, no need to know how many items you are expecting.

Comment: Well I didn't think of that. It works, obviously, so thanks a lot. But if anyone can explain why counting didn't work for me, go ahead. I'm still curious.

Comment: This is a work-around. I would like to understand that too.